# Versioning and polymorphic associations

Tags: activerecord

I'm creating a second version of my app using using the following pattern:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listable_items
  has_many :lists, through: :listable_items, source: :listable, source_type: 'List'
end

class ListableItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
end

module V2
  class List < List
    has_many :listable_items
    has_many :lists, through: :listable_items, source: :listable, source_type: 'V2::List'

    self.inheritance_column = :_non_existing_column 
  end
end

Module V2
  class ListableItem < ListableItem
    belongs_to :list, class_name: "V2::List"
    belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true

  end
end

list = V2::List.find_by(slug: "people")
=> #<V2::List:0x007fd6e9007f18 id: 97, title: "People"....>

list.listable_items
=> [#<V2::ListableItem:0x007fd6e6497ec8 id: 2633, list_id: 97, listable_id: 100, listable_type: "List",....]

list.listable_items.first.listable
=> #<List:0x007fd6e4185868 id: 100,...>
```

I assume this is happening because of the class definition in the listable_type column of ListableItems.  Is there a way to have it refer to the V2 version of the model instead of the one defined in the db column when I call the associated record?

adding

```
def listable_type
  "V2::" + super
end
```

to the ListableItem class didn't change the class of the called listable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to over-write the listable method, not the listable_type method.  There may very well be a better way to do this, but this way worked for me.

```
Module V2
  class ListableItem < ListableItem
    belongs_to :list, class_name: "V2::List"
    belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true

    def listable
      ("V2::" + listable_type).constantize.find(listable_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.